# How can i saveOrUpdate in hibernate where the changed field is not the id

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

The scenario is :

The id is identity generated. I have a field "key" (not id)which i need to check while saveOrUpdate. If "Key" is changed, i need to update the database with the updated key and value. So the scenario becomes like, i want to update the database based on a particular field(here "key") change and not the id value change.

```
<class name="Data" table="DATA">
     <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>    
    <property name="Key" type="string" not-null="true" index="dedupeKey_Index">
        <column name="Key" length="100" />
    </property>

    <property name="Value" type="string">
        <column name="Value" length="100" />
    </property>

    <property name="insertedDate"
        type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime">
        <column name="insertedDate" />
    </property> 


</class>
```

How can i do this?Is there any way to forcefully make hibernate make my field "key" to refer while saveOrUpdate and not the id!!

I thought of making a composite key. But then I cant create a generator for "id", which is required!!

Thanks guys in advance!!